# Common names for the screen that appears when your phone rings

Tags: android

I want to change this screen on my phone to be different.  So, I am looking through the source and trying to google up examples related to this screen... I am not getting many hits, so I guess that I am using the wrong name for this screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try answer screen? or phone answer screen?